# How to split a string before a dot in Lua?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I need to do a simple split of a string.

The string is `"That.Awkward.Moment.2014.720p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.srt"`

I just need `"That.Awkward.Moment.2014.720p.BluRay.x264.YIFY"` without `".srt"`

I tried this and is wrong:

```
print(string.match("That.Awkward.Moment.2014.720p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.srt", '^.-.s'))
```

How would I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since regular matching is greedy, you just need to match anything until you see `.` (don't forget to escape it):

```
print(string.match("That.Awkward.Moment.2014.720p.BluRay.x264.YIFY.srt", '(.+)%.(.+)'))
```

will print

```
That.Awkward.Moment.2014.720p.BluRay.x264.YIFY  srt
```